# How to rewrite url using mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, url, mod-rewrite, seo

My urls currently look like this:

```
http://domain.com/news/articles.php?id=22&category=investments&title=securing-your-future-making-the-right-investment
```

How can I use mod_rewrite to make the url look more like this:

```
http://domain.com/news/articles/investments/securing-your-future-making-the-right-investment
```

EDIT: need to include the id variable too

Comment: Will your script not require the id variable too?

Comment: oops yes id variable would be important

Comment: There are at least 5,000 questions - probably more - on Stack Overflow that are more or less a variation of this, just with different variable names. Also  Googling "rewrite URL mod_rewrite" will give dozens of useful tutorials and step-by-step guides. Why not try to do some research yourself first? It's not that hard, even if you don't know anything about mod_rewrite. If you get stuck with something in the process, you can still always ask here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#enable mod rewrite
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/news/articles.php?id=([0-9]+)&category=([a-zA-Z]+)&title=([a-zA-Z]+)$ /news/articles/$2/$1_$3
```

the ID must exist in the URL so the it looks like:

http://domain.com/news/articles/investments/{ID}_securing-your-future-making-the-right-investment

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

**Add something like this to your .htaccess file:**

> ^/news/articles/([0-9]+)/(.*)$securing-your-future-making-the-right-investment$
>   /news/articles.php?id=$1&category=$3s&title=$2 [L]

Don't know about the $3, but category doesn't seem to be present in the url you listed so I guess it isnt needed.

This should make it work ;)